# Retrieve records with multple matches in link table

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with SQL and would value some assistance.

I have a main table and a one-to-many link table in mySQL, joined by oppreg_id. I want to retrieve all the records on the main table that have multiple matches to the field activity_id in the link table.

```
main table            link table
oppreg                oppreg2activity
---------------       -----------------
oppreg_id   ---->     oppreg_id
title                 activity_id
description
end_date
...
```

So I might have

```
oppreg_id = 4563 in the main table
```

and records in the oppreg2activity table

```
oppreg_id  activity_ID
  4563      27e17f2e
  4563      38d6bd73
  4563      ....
```

I've tried SQL like

```
SELECT oppreg.`oppreg_id`,`title`,`description`, activity_id 
FROM `oppreg` 
INNER JOIN oppreg2activity ON oppreg.oppreg_id = oppreg2activity.oppreg_id
GROUP BY `oppreg_id`
HAVING 
  activity_id = '27e17f2e' 
  AND activity_id = '38d6bd73'
```

This works when one WHERE item is present but fails on multiple ones.

I also need to include the additional restriction

```
oppreg.end_date >= CURDATE()
```

but can't see how to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion to aggregate by `oppreg_id` is correct, but you should but asserting counts in the `HAVING` clause, instead of using plain equalities.

```
SELECT
    o.oppreg_id
FROM oppreg o
INNER JOIN oppreg2activity oa
    ON o.oppreg_id = oa.oppreg_id
WHERE
    oa.activity_id IN ('27e17f2e', '38d6bd73') AND
    o.end_date >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY
    o.oppreg_id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id) = 2;
```

Note that it only makes sense to select the `title` and `description` if the `oppreg_id` column be a primary key in the `oppreg` table.  If not, then we would have to do an additional join to bring in this extra information.

As for an explanation of the query, it works by attempting to reduce down each `oppreg_id` group to only those records having the two specified `activity_id` values.  It then aggregates and asserts using `COUNT` that two distinct `activity_id` are present, which, if true, implies that this `oppreg_id` group is a match.

Comment: Yes, I should have said that oppreg_id is the primary key. This is just what I need. Many thanks. Now could somebody explain why it is necessary to add the count?

Comment: Putting it another way, if I've understood. The IN keyword is an abbreviated form for a set of OR statements. The count is needed to limit the results to instances where all occur, effectively turning it into an AND statement.

Comment: @magnol I couldn't have phrased it better myself, great comment above.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need where for filter date and `count` for multipe entry checking

```
SELECT oppreg.`oppreg_id`,
`title`,`description`, activity_id 
FROM `oppreg` 
INNER JOIN oppreg2activity ON oppreg.oppreg_id = oppreg2activity.oppreg_id
where oppreg.end_date >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY oppreg.`oppreg_id`,
`title`,`description`, activity_id
having count(*)>1
```